# Certificate Exception connecting to Azure SQL with JDBC with default connection string (the one the management console says to use)

Tags: jdbc, azure

I'm wanting to connect to an Azure SQL Server from jdbc.

I copy the connection string from the azure management console. It is something like:

> jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX.database.windows.net:1433;database=YYYY;user=ZZZZZ@XXXX;password=PPPPPPPPPPP;encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net

When I try and connect with this value I get the following error:

> **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not
>   establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) encryption. Error:
>   "java.security.cert.CertificateException: Failed to validate the
>   server name in a certificate during Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
>   initialization. The server name is *.database.windows.net, the name in
>   certificate is data.am2-1.database.windows.net.**

Then if I change the *.database.windows.net to data.am2-1.database.windows.net as it says in the exception it works fine.

So is it a problem to set this name? I feel like if it is a wild card as default then it is probably going to change? and when it does I assume I won't be able to connect anymore.
Has anyone else had this issue? I am using the most up to date jdbc drivers for SQL Server that I could find.

Comment: Seeing the same issue occasionally in v10.2.0.jre8 using Azure WebApp and Azure SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out an upgrade of the sql server jdbc version to version 4.0 cleaned up the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add `trustServerCertificate=true` in your connection string, but it's not recommended from a security perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue on JDBC driver version 4.1, downgrading to 4.0 resolved issue