# Azure WebJobs can't connect to SQL using encrypted communication

Tags: java, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs

I have a Java application running as a WebJob on Azure. This job tries to connect to my Azure SQL Server. If the encryption is on, I get a connection error:

```
The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "java.security.cert.CertificateException: Failed to validate the server name in a certificate during Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) initialization.".
```

If `encrypt = false` it connects fine.

Shouldn't the communication between resources in Azure always be encrypted?

Also, if I run the application locally, the database connection successfully connects in encrypted mode.

Comment: Seeing the same issue occasionally in v10.2.0.jre8 using Azure WebApp and Azure SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First- I should explain that Azure SQL DB is always going to default to an encrypted connection. The error you're seeing is speaking of *verifying the identity* of the server that you're communicating with as part of the handshake for SSL. [There's some unpacking of this idea over here.] (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/how-does-an-ssl-server-prove-its-identity)

I unpacked the encryption of communication with Azure SQL Database in answers on this [MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/876003a8-3fda-407b-812e-38e152325fce/re-encrypting-data-in-transit?forum=ssdsgetstarted#734e5497-30a3-4bb2-97da-28c02bea3473)- but I'll bring the relevant portion here:

```
When using Azure SQL DB, connections are encrypted even when the connection
string does not include those portions we recommend. 
...
Encryption occurs only if there is a verifiable server certificate,
otherwise the connection attempt fails.
```

Your error, as outlined on this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb879949(v=sql.110).aspx), arises from the following situation:

```
If the encrypt property is set to true and the trustServerCertificate 
property is set to false and if the server name in the connection string 
does not match the server name in the SQL Server SSL certificate, the 
following error will be issued: The driver could not establish a secure 
connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. 
Error: "java.security.cert.CertificateException: Failed to validate the
server name in a certificate during Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) initialization."
```

Apparently, the JDBC driver for SQL Server 4.0 seems to resolve this error: 
[Azure VM Fails to Connect to Azure SQL Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854002/azure-vm-fails-to-connect-to-azure-sql-service)

[Certificate Exception connecting to Azure SQL with JDBC with default connection string (the one the management console says to use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755951/certificate-exception-connecting-to-azure-sql-with-jdbc-with-default-connection)

Comment: I am using PaaS (Azure's WebApp and SQL Server).

I tried version 4.0.2206.100 of Microsoft's JDBC driver and now it works in encrypted mode. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: Glad it worked. I'll make sure that's filed as a regression tomorrow. (I'll also try and explain why this happens, but I want to verify with the team on the reasoning before I post here- for accuracy sake.)

Comment: Thanks Dan! Appreciate it.

Comment: Paul - I gave my answer an update, but am still working with a few people over here to track down exactly why this is behavior in the newer JDBC drivers.